# Prove this series is divergent: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sin kx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I need to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sin kx$  is divergent when $x \notin \pi \Bbb Z$.

I tried to solve this equation with it's sums' seria but I didn't succeed. I'll be glad for some help.

Comment: Hint: Does $\sin(kx)$ converge to zero?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: (Edited incorporating Carl's comments)

$\sin kx $ doesn't tend to $0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$, for $x \notin \mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: This is indeed a hint, but a hard one, because the fact that $\sin(kx)$ doesn't converge to $0$ unless $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$ is not an elementary result.

Comment: @Carl Very true. I guess the hint by user45105 is more appropriate.

Comment: That is basically the same hint as this one, except that it only considers one $x$, when the problem asks for all of them.

Comment: @Carl Yes we both have addressed only a tiny part of the problem (making it a hard hint). But your first comment takes care of the rest. Hadn't seen this when I wrote the hint. Thanks for the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using the divergence test that is; if $\sum {{a_k}} $ converges then $a_k \to 0$, however in our case $\sin(kx)$ does not converges to $0$, e.g. take $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$.